# Getting prints in the form of list and accessing each of those

Tags: python, string, list, extract, checkstyle

```
from myfolder import typing_commands as tcm
import sys, StringIO
class InfoTest(StartUpTest):
    IS_TEST = True
    def __init__(self):
        super(InfoTest, self).__init__()

    def setup(self):
        return

    def runtest(self):
        tcm.erase_flash()
        self.boot() # boot method is defined in StartUpTest class
        time.sleep(20)
        tcm.info_read() #Here it prints all the info see o/p1

        #To get The printed data in list form
        old_stdout = sys.stdout
        capturer = StringIO.StringIO()
        sys.stdout = capturer
        tcm.info_read()
        sys.stdout = old_stdout
        output = capturer.getvalue().splitlines()

        for each in output[8:]:
            print each, type(each)
        print type(output)  #see o/p2
        return
```

o/p1:

```
Info as desired:
Downloading Logs...
Info Downloaded!

####################
Info Entry 1:
####################
        Type                : Survey
        Survey_time         : 2014-09-05 10:10:40
        Inclination    (deg): 45
        Temperature     (C) : 30.00
        Battery_Voltage (mV): 24.0
```

o/p2:

```
        Survey_time         : 2014-09-05 10:11:44 <type 'str'>
        Inclination    (deg): 45 <type 'str'>
        Temperature     (C) : 30.00 <type 'str'>
        Battery_Voltage (mV): 24.0 <type 'str'>

<type 'list'>
```

Now my problem is though I'm able to get the `output` in the form of list, `each` of `output` is actually a `str`. I want to check if `Battery_Voltage` is in the range i.e greater than 20V and same like for others eg. `Temperature` and `Inclination`. How should I extract *values for each* so that I can perform a check on them? Also I had to hardcoded it to reach out to my set of checks eg.

```
for each in output[8:]:
            print each, type(each)
```

Is there any better way to do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, when you obtain `output` you do:

```
output = capturer.getvalue().splitlines()
```

Now... here you *never* convert the contents of the `StringIO` (which are `str`ings) to other types. The elements in the `output` lists are all strings, and even those you are interested in (`output[8:]`) are strings of the form `some name: number`, so python cannot possibly magically understand that you are interested in the *number* part and automagically convert those value for you.

You want to explicitly convert the numbers that are represented in those strings.

To convert a string to a number you can simply call `float` (or `int` for integers):

```
>>> float('1.0')
1.0
>>> type(float('1.0'))
<class 'float'>
```

In your case there are some dates that you don't want to convert. These will raise a `ValueError` when you pass them to `float`.

For example:

```
import contextlib

capturer = StringIO.StringIO()
with contextlib.redirect_stdout(capturer):
    tcm.info_read()
output = capturer.getvalue().splitlines()

for line in output[8:]:
    name, value = line.split(':')
    try:
        value = float(value)
    except ValueError:
        # this is a date. Keep it as a string or do something else.
        pass
    print(name, ':', value, type(value))
```

If you are using python<3.4 instead of [`contextlib.redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) you can use `sys.__stdout__` to restore the old value:

```
sys.stdout = StringIO.StringIO()
tcm.info_read()
output = sys.stdout.getvalue().splitlines()
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

Once you have converted your values you can do all the checks you want with them (which probably will depend on the `name` part)

---

As I suggestion: I'd build a `dict` from that data, so that you can easily access the different values by name:

```
data = {}
for line in output[8:]:
    name, value = line.split(':')
    try:
        value = float(value)
    except ValueError:
        # this is a date. Keep it as a string or do something else.
        pass
    data[name.strip().split()[0].lower()] = value
```

Afterwards you can do:

```
if data['temperature'] > 50:
    print('Temperature above 50 C')
elif data['battery_voltage'] < 20:
    print('Voltage too low')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also another approach which is more flexible and you have better control over the conditions which have to be applied to those values. This could be helpful when there are lots of fields to be processed and you need to do some more complex stuff.

We may dynamically call for every field a method specific for this particular description. For example, when the field with description Battery is being processed, we call *process_battery* of class *FieldProcessor* and so on.

So in your printing function:

```
for each in output[8:]:
            print each, type(each)
```

I would add some code like this:

```
import re, sys
from collections import namedtuple

for each in output[8:]:

   # I prefer using namedtuple so we can use tuple.description and tuple.value
   field = namedtuple("field", "description value")

   # Regular expression for extracting the description and value
   # May be optimized, play with it :) takes description containing A-Z,a-z,_
   result = re.findall(r'^ *([A-Za-z_]*).*: (.*)$', each)
   if len(result):

       # Make namedtuple from tuple
       field = field._make(result[0])

       processor = FieldProcessor()

       # Get function of FieldProcessor with description name
       process_func = getattr(processor, 'process_'+field.description.lower(), None)

       if callable(process_func):
           process_func(field)

   else:
       print "Cannot parse field "+each
```

Then we can have FieldProcessor class, where you can do anything with your values. I expect there is no problem with converting str to float etc.

```
class FieldProcessor:
    def process_voltage(self, field):
        pass

    def process_inclination(self, field):
        # Converting to float, int, ...
        if field.value > 20:
            print "Inclination more then 20"

    def process_survey_time(self, field):
        pass

    def process_temperature(self, field):
        pass
```